# Does this FFT algorithm give correct IFFT when the input does not contain symmetry?

Tags: fft, ifft, java

This FFT function is from Numerical Recipies in C and I am using it in my java projects. The source code is given below:

```
void fft_function(double datain[], int nn, int isign)
{
    // input
    // datain[0]: ignore
    // datain[1]: Re1
    // datain[2]: Im1 (=0)
    // datain[3]: Re2
    // datain[4]: Im2 (=0)
    // ....
    // output:
    // datain[0]: ignore
    // datain[1]: Re1
    // datain[2]: Im1 (= 0, dc value)
    // datain[3]: Re2
    // datain[4]: Im2
    // ....
    // nn = FFT size (power of 2)
    // isign : 1 -> FFT, -- -> IFFT

    int n;

    double temp_data;
    int  mmax, m, j, istep, i;
    double wtemp, wr, wpr, wpi, wi, theta;
    double tempr, tempi;

    n=2*nn;
    j = 1;

    // This is the bit-reversal section of the routine.
    for (i=1;i<n;i+=2) {        // for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (j > i) {

            temp_data = datain[j];
            datain[j] = datain[i];
            datain[i] = temp_data;
            temp_data = datain[j+1];
            datain[j+1] = datain[i+1];
            datain[i+1] = temp_data;
        }
        m = n/2;
        while (m >= 2 && j > m) {
            j -= m;
            m = m/2;
        }

        j += m;
    }

    //Here begins the Danielson - Lanczos section of the routine.
    mmax = 2;
    //Outer loop executed log2 nn times.
    while (n > mmax) {
        istep = mmax *2;
        //Initialize the trigonometric recurrence.
        theta = ((double)isign*6.28318530717959f) / (double)mmax;       // theta = 6.28318530717959f / (double)isign*mmax;
        wtemp=Math.sin(0.5f*theta);
        wpr = -2.0f*wtemp*wtemp;
        wpi=Math.sin(theta);

        wr = 1.0f;
        wi = 0.0f;
        //Here are the two nested inner loops.
        for (m = 1; m < mmax; m += 2) {        // for (m = 1; m <= mmax; m += 2) {
            for (i = m; i <= n; i += istep) {
                //This is the Danielson-Lanczos formula:
                j = i + mmax;
                tempr = wr * datain[j] - wi * datain[j + 1];
                tempi = wr * datain[j + 1] + wi * datain[j];
                datain[j] = datain[i] - tempr;
                datain[j + 1] = datain[i + 1] - tempi;
                datain[i] += tempr;
                datain[i + 1] += tempi;
            }
            //Trigonometric recurrence.
            wtemp=wr;
            wr = wr*wpr - wi*wpi + wr;
            wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi;
        }
        mmax = istep;
    }

}
```

This gives perfect results when doing something like `a = FFT[real array], IFFT[a] = real array`, that is, if I do an fft of a real array, I get an imaginary array with the required symmetry. If I input the same imaginary array and get an IFFT, I get the real array back.

However, I need to find the IFFT of a complex array that will not necessarily have the positive and negative symmetry of a complex array that results from taking an FFT of a real array. For example, I would like to find a the IFFT of something like this:

```
0.12 + 0.023i
0.15 + 0.2i
0.235+ 0.006i
-0.562 + 0.36i
-0.663 - 0.566i
0.23 - 0.56i
0.889 - 0.226i
0.001 + 0.221i
```

I think this algorithm will not work in that case, and I am not getting the same results as a matlab IFFT for the same input.

1. Am I correct that this algorithm does not work when the complex array does not have the required symmetry?
2. What can I do to find the IFFT in such a case? Can it be done by an easy modification to this code or is it more complex?

Comment: Looking at the isign parameter that controls forward vs inverse transforms, and the rest of the parameter list, I don’t see why it wouldn’t work. Looks like it handles complex in and out. Are you certain you are packing your data into the array correctly?

Comment: @DanSzabo I think so, as far as I can tell, but I am not getting same result for this ifft and matlab ifft for the same input. I just want a second opinion on if i am doing this correctly. Also, it works if the complex array has symmetry. I want to know if this algorithm still works if the complex array is asymmetric